# Why does light travel in straight paths?

Tags: optics, visible-light, conservation-laws

Why light travels in straight paths? What's the real cause that makes light photons to go in a straight line? and what are the factors that could change the path of light externally? (I'm excluding reflection, refraction and deviation here.)

Comment: Just as a side note, in regions where material properties vary continuously light can follow curved paths. This phenomena is a big contributor to road-bad mirages.

Comment: What kind of an answer are you looking for? General relativity basically almost postulates this. Quantum or classical domain (or both)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Light has momentum.

$p = h/\lambda $

Light must travel in a straight line for momentum to be conserved.

Comment: One of the best answers on this site: love how it cuts through to a core physical principle in two lines, although I think the form $\vec{p}=\hbar\,\vec{k}$ better illustrates your pithy point.

Answer (score 5):

It's valid to look at light as a wave - it's just like a radio wave - and waves travel by self-interference.

If you think of every point on a wave front as if it were a point source making its own ripples, you would see that the ripples cancel each other out in every possible direction except straight forward.

Actually, that's only true in a flat relativistic space, or in a medium where the speed of light is constant.
The easiest example where this isn't so is if the light beam goes into a prism or through the surface of water.
At a boundary like that, the speed of light changes, so the beam changes direction.

Answer (score 1):

The Lagrangian of a light ray is given by,

$$\mathcal{L} = \mu(y) \left[ 1+ \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}y(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)^2\right]^{1/2}$$

where $\mu$ is the refractive index, a function of the path. The associated equations of motion are,

$$\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial y} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}} + \left[  \frac{y''y'}{\sqrt{(1+y'^2)^3}} - \frac{\mu y''(x)}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}} - \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial y} \frac{y'^2}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}\right] = 0$$

If we set the refractive index to a constant, i.e. $\mu=\text{const.}$ then the equations of motion reduce to,

$$\frac{y''y'}{\sqrt{(1+y'^2)^3}} - \frac{\mu y''(x)}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}=0$$

which is a second-order nonlinear differential equation. It can be shown the only solutions are,

$$y(x)=c_1x+c_2$$

These solutions are linear functions, hence simply straight paths which is the required result, providing the medium which the light travels through is uniform and constant.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give other ways of getting to the same answer.

First of all, the wonderful [path integral formulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation) (which can be found in Feynman's excellent book, "QED"):

In order to consider the probability of a particle from going to a point $A$ to a pont $B$, you consider ALL the possible paths. Each path has a probability contribution and we just have to sum them up (integrate, to be more precise). You might want to watch this [video](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation), where each contribution is represented by an arrow.

[image]

The contribution of each trajectory, will roughly depened on the time taken. But this is the Quantum Mechanical view, the thing is that all the deviations from a straight line tend to cancel out, giving us a straight line in the classical limit.

This interpretation has a deep importance in modern physics since it applies not only to photons, but to any other particle. It would be written mathematicaly as:

$$\langle \text{fina state} \vert e^{-iHt} \vert \text{inital state} \rangle = \int e^{iS[x]} Dx(t)$$

Where $S$ is the classical action, as seen in Hamiltonian mechanics.

Another, quite similar view, is that light travels in a way it minimizes the time (this is not true in the case of mirrors, it might be a maximum, but we are no interested in that). This is called [Fermat's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_principle) and can be derived from Huygen's principle (which Mike Dunlavey explained).

So in free space, the way you arrive earliest is by going in a straight light.